# Is it haram to call a person your idol as wanting to be like him and not worshipping him?

Tags: halal-haram, shirk

I wanted to know is it haram to call a person your idol? And by idol I am not meaning that I want to worship him, by idol I'm meaning that I want to be like him, is it still haram?

Answer (score 1):

**Bismillah Hir Rahmaan Nir Raheem**

**As Salaamu 3laykum,**

I hope you are doing well. There is no harm with you looking up to someone however the word idol should not be used. By definition idol according to dictionary.com is:

[image]

After accepting Islam we do not have blind admiration for anything/anyone except ALLAH (Glory Be To Him) and His Prophet (Peace Be Upon Him). Instead we can say I look up to or admire this person/thing. In that case then there is no harm. With that being said I would to present to you some criteria to make sure we look up to those things/people that will be of benefit to us.

In the Quraan:

> O you who have believed, do not take as intimates those other than yourselves [i.e., believers], for they will not spare you [any] ruin. They wish you would have hardship. Hatred has already appeared from their mouths, and what their breasts conceal is greater. We have certainly made clear to you the signs, if you will use reason. (Chapter 3 verse 118).

In the Ahadith:

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said: A man follows the religion of his friend; so each one should consider whom he makes his friend. (Abu Dawud in the chapter of general behavior)

> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "The example of a good companion (who sits with you) in comparison with a bad one, is like that of the musk seller and the blacksmith's bellows (or furnace); from the first you would either buy musk or enjoy its good smell while the bellows would either burn your clothes or your house, or you get a bad nasty smell thereof." (Bukhari in the chapter of sales and trade)

With the aforementioned information on hand we come to the conclusion that having good company and looking up to good people is the correct way. Everything in our lives is a tug of war either towards good or towards bad, positive or negative. That is why we have been told to strive hard towards positive so we can meet a positive end (Jannah). Ameen.

**Have a nice day!**

Comment: So, do I have to repent to my sins even though i wasn't meaning it that way?

Comment: As Salaamu 3laykum, i hope you are doing well. As long as you did not intend it in the wrong way you are fine. There is a hadith that says actions are by intentions. And in the Quraan in chapter 33 verse 5 it states ".......And there is no blame upon you for that in which you have erred but [only for] what your hearts intended. And ever is Allah Forgiving and Merciful." Have a good day!

Answer (score -2):

No, it is not haram if you use the word this way

Comment: This hardly looks like a useful answer please elaborate and check [answer].